# How to make three dropdown in same line,Using zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a page , where i need to show 3 drop down in same line.

Iam generating these drop downs using zend form.

Now the drop down is coming one line after one line.

How can we make it in same line

Answer (score 0):

Zend form comes with decorators. If decorators are set (which is used for template theming purpose) with '' or any other Html tag then there is a possibility that the element will be displayed in new line. Try with removing decorators.

Or you can generate select element dyanamicly on .phtml (view file) by using code

```
$this->formSelect("ID", "default value", array('style' => 'width:60px', 'class' => 'progDiv'), $options);

Where $options is an array of select box options like `$options = array(''=>'', 1=>'option1', 2=>'option2');`
```

If this does not solve your query please try to post your code

Thanks